# Finding non-secure items in internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl, warnings

I was wondering if there is a tool, bookmarklet or something out there that can help me find non-secure items on a page. When I view source and search for http:// on the https page in question I find the following items:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
...

<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0" width="940" height="152">
...  
pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
```

These things seem relatively "standard" and in fact ssl works completely fine in both Firefox and in Chrome while it does not in IE!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually... It seems that one of those things actually did cause issue... i removed http: from each of the links

so: http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer
became: //www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer

and everything works fine now...

The odd thing is, those pages don't need to be downloaded. This is somewhat surprising (also considering ff,chrome and others don't complain).